# React component not reading this.props correctly

Tags: reactjs

I have a react component which receives props from it's parent, App.js. This works correctly. I can console.log() this:

```
componentWillReceiveProps(props) {
  console.log(props);
  this.getPosts()
}
```

console.log() correctly shows the props here:

```
{pageNumber: 2, loggedIn: true}
```

However, in my getPosts() method, I read from `this.props`:

```
getPosts() {
  console.log("in post list and page is" + this.props.pageNumber)
}
```

And it prints:

```
in post list and page is 1
```

It always lags behind 1 count, no matter what--meaning, when props has a pageNumber value of 3, it prints as 2, props has a value of 4, it prints as 3, etc. This is causing me to fetch the incorrect posts while paginating server side.

How can I get the correct value?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

props you received is the next new props and this.props is not yet updated at this lifecycle stage. you probably should pass props directly to getPosts(props.pageNumber) instead

https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/react-component.html#componentwillreceiveprops
`componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps)`

> componentWillReceiveProps() is invoked before a mounted component
>   receives new props. If you need to update the state in response to
>   prop changes (for example, to reset it), you may compare this.props
>   and nextProps and perform state transitions using this.setState() in
>   this method.

Answer (score 2):

You are calling `getPosts` from the `componentWillReceiveProps` function. At this point of time the, the original props of the component have not updated, so accessing `this.props.pageNumber` in `getPosts` doesn't show the updated props, you should pass the nextProps to the getPosts function and then access it like

```
componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps) {
  console.log(nextProps);
  this.getPosts(nextProps);
}

getPosts(nextProps) {
    console.log("in post list and page is" + nextProps.pageNumber)
}
```